# WEKA does not recognise different attributes from a .csv file

Tags: csv, data-mining, weka, converters, arff

I have a problem when opening a dataset in WEKA. While in its .csv format all the variables and respective values are clearly distinguished, in WEKA I only have one attribute which looks like this:

PINCP; AGEP; LANX; RACWHT; RACBLK; RACASN; SEX; etc.

and the values associated look similar, being separated by a semicolon as well.

Do you have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Your dataset, on the other hand, uses semi-colons as separator between cells.

When opening your dataset in the Weka Explorer, check the *Invoke options dialog* box in the file chooser dialog. Then change the *fieldSeparator* option from a comma to a semi-colon.

In case you are using the command-line for loading your dataset, use the `-F` option of the [CSVLoader](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.html) class.